# Disable "Extrude region together along the average normal" dragable UI element

Tags: interface, edit-mode

The yellow circle with the `+` icon. I pressed something accidentally on my keyboard, but I don't know what. I don't know how to get rid of it either. I suspect it has to do with the "Show Overlays" setting in the drop down above the view controls in the top-right of the view port, but I've tried all the options in there, none of them disable this circle with the `+`.

[image]

Comment: Everybody: for questions like this one see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1):

in the tools menu on the left side of your 3D viewport press on this icon

[image]

Or just press <kbd>W</kbd> to select the same tool "Select Box".